# How to extract text from PDF with formatted layout (spacing, alignment) in Python or ASP.NET Core?

Tags: itext

I've been working on extracting text from PDFs in both Python and ASP.NET Core using various libraries such as iTextSharp, PDFSharp, PyPDF2, and others. While these libraries successfully extract text, I'm facing challenges in preserving the formatted layout, including spacing and alignment.

Is there a recommended approach or library in Python or ASP.NET Core that can accurately extract text from PDFs while maintaining the original formatted layout? I want to ensure that the extracted text reflects the original spacing, alignment, and overall visual structure of the PDF.

I have tried using PyMuPDF and Camelot, but the results are not as expected. I would appreciate any insights, code snippets, or library recommendations that can help achieve this goal.

---

but the output of both code is as below it extract text in this way

```
Invoice#
Invoice Date
Terms
Due Date: INV-000003
: 18 May 2023
: Due on
Receipt
: 18 May 2023
Bill To Ship To
Ms. Mary D. Dunton 1324 Hinkle Lake Road
1324 Hinkle Lake Road Needham
Needham 02192 Maine
02192 Maine
# Item & Description Qty Rate Amount
1 Camera
DSLR camera with
advanced shooting
capabilities1 $899.00 $899.00
2 Fitness Tracker
Activity tracker with heart
rate monitoring1 $129.00 $129.00
3 Laptop
Lightweight laptop with a
powerful processor1 $1,199.00 $1,199.00
$2,227.00
5.00%
$2,338.35
Thanks for shopping with us. $2,338.35Zylker Electronics Hub
14B, Northern Street Greater South Avenue
New York New York 10001 U.S.A
Sub Total
Balance DueINVOICE
TotalTax Rate
```

---

But it should show like below as original PDF looks

```
Zylker Electronics Hub                                                                                 
14B, Northern Street Greater South Avenue                                                              
New York New York 10001 U.S.A                                                     INVOICE              
Invoice#                                    : INV-000003                                               
Invoice Date                                : 18 May 2023                                              
Terms                                       : Due on                                                   
Due Date                                    Receipt                                                    
                                            : 18 May 2023                                              
Bill To                                                     Ship To                                    
Ms. Mary D. Dunton                                          1324 Hinkle Lake Road                      
1324 Hinkle Lake Road                                       Needham                                    
Needham                                                     02192 Maine                                
02192 Maine                                                                                            
#             Item & Description                                           Qty          Rate             
1             Camera                                                         1       $899.00    
              DSLR camera with                                                                         
              advanced shooting                                                                        
              capabilities                                                                             
2             Fitness Tracker                                                 1      $129.00    
              Activity tracker with heart                                                              
              rate monitoring                                                                          
                                                                                                       
3              Laptop                                                         1     $1,199.00 
               Lightweight laptop with a                                                               
               powerful processor                                                                      
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                       
                                                                Sub Total    $2,338.35
                                                                Tax Rate        5.00%                  
                                                                Total         $2,338.35            
Thanks for shopping with us.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. If you haven't tried anything, make an effort. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: As you tagged your question with [tag:itext] and only with that tag,  i assume your question is focused on iText. In that case you appear to be using the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` which assumes that the text is drawn in reading order. First you should try the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. That should sort the output as desired. After checking that that indeed improves the output,  please search for the `LayoutTextExtractionStrategy` in older answers here. That should additionally output the desired spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample it hard to say what works for one layout compared to another However here is a sample using a recent copy of the oldest PDFtoTeXT utility as a drag and drop but you will find it in most Python suites. clearly it cannot without extra work extract the graphics.

[image]

Result of fixed pitch 4.5 in this layout case looks best

```
                                                                                                        Invoice
                                                                                                           Invoice# INV-17

          Zylker                                                                                                  Balance Due
          4141 Hacienda Dr
          Pleasanton California 94588
                                                                                                                 $562.750
          U.S.A



                                                                                      Invoice Date :             03 May 2018

                                                                                            Terms :           Due On Receipt
          Bill To
          Rob & Joe Traders                                                              Due Date :              03 May 2018
          2708 Southside Lane
          Los Angeles                                                                        P.O.# :                  321014
          90018 CA
          USA                                                                        Project Name :            Design project



             #     Item & Description                                   Qty         Rate    Discount               Amount

             1     Brochure Design                                      1.00     300.000         0.00               300.000
                   Brochure Design Single Sided Color


             2     Web Design Packages(Template) - Basic                1.00     250.000         0.00               250.000
                   Custom Themes for your business. Inclusive of 10
                   hours of marketing and annual training


             3     Print Ad - Basic - Color                             1.00      80.000         0.00                80.000
                   Print Ad 1/8 size Color


                                                                                            Sub Total               630.000

                                                                                 Sample Tax1 (4.70%)                 11.750

                                                                                 Sample Tax2 (7.00%)                 21.000


                                                                                               Total              $662.750


                                                                                      Payment Made               (-) 100.000


                                                                                        Balance Due               $562.750




          Notes
          Thanks for your business.


          Payment Options



          Terms & Conditions
          Please pay the Invoice before the due date.




                                                                                                                            1

                                     This sample invoice template was created using
```

Here is that TRY.BAT file for fast testing 1st run uses first line then based on results (between 4 and 5 looked good) `rem` is moved from 3rd line to first line and integer changed to 4.# for finer results where 4.5 looked best.

```
rem for /L %%f in (1,1,9) do pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk -f 1 -l 1 -enc UTF-8 -x 0 -y 0 -W 600 -H 840 -fixed %%f "%~1"  "%~dpn1-%%f.txt"
REM result looks best in this case between 4 and 5 so lets try 4.1 to 4.9
for /L %%f in (1,1,9) do pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk -f 1 -l 1 -enc UTF-8 -x 0 -y 0 -W 600 -H 840 -fixed 4.%%f "%~1"  "%~dpn1-4.%%f.txt"
pause
```